# in 'require' loading error

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run a Ruby file that enables leap motion for sphero (version 2.0.0). I'm having troubles with the loading error when I try running from cmd.

The code for the ruby file:

```
    require 'em-websocket'
    require 'sphero'

    Sphero.start "/dev/tty.Sphero-RWP-AMP-SPP" do |s|
      puts "Connected to Sphero!"
      sleep 1
      3.times do
        begin
          s.color 'green'
        rescue
        end
      end
      keep_going 1
      s.color 'black'
      calibration = 0

EM.run {
EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|

  mutex_sphero = Mutex.new
  mutex_req = Mutex.new
  req = nil

  ws.onopen { |handshake|
    puts "WebSocket connection open"
  }

  ws.onclose { puts "Connection closed" }

  ws.onmessage { |msg|
    puts "Recieved message: #{msg}"

    if msg == 'start'
      mutex_sphero.synchronize { s.color 'blue', true }

    elsif msg == 'stop'
      mutex_sphero.synchronize {
        s.color 'black', true
        stop
        mutex_req.synchronize { req = nil }
      }

    elsif msg == 'calibrate+' or msg == 'calibrate-'
      mutex_sphero.synchronize {
        s.color 'black'
        s.back_led_output = 0xff
        calibration = (calibration + (msg == "calibrate+" ? 15 : 360-15)) % 360
        puts "calibration = #{calibration}"
        s.roll 0, calibration
      }
      EM.cancel_timer(@calib_timer) if @calib_timer
      @calib_timer = EM.add_timer(3) do
        mutex_sphero.synchronize { s.back_led_output = 0 }
      end

    else
      data = msg.split(',').map {|d| d.to_i }
      speed = [Math.sqrt(data[0]**2 + data[1]**2)*20, 0xff].min.to_i
      deg = Math.atan2(data[0], data[1]) / Math::PI * 180
      deg = (deg + calibration + 360) % 360
      p [speed, deg.to_i]

      mutex_req.synchronize { req = [speed, deg.to_i] }
      EM.defer do                      
        mutex_sphero.synchronize do
          r = nil
          mutex_req.synchronize { r, req = req, r } 
          s.roll *r if r                
          end

        end
      }
    end
   }

end
```

Here's the error:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53;in 'require' cannot load such file -- C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\em-websocket.gem <LoadError>
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in 'require'
from websocket-sphero.rb:3:in '<main>'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you have this file https://github.com/mwylde/em-websocket-client/blob/master/lib/em-websocket-client.rb

Comment: Nope, I tried downloading the file and running it, but the same error from above came in.

Comment: The backtrace is using forward slash for directory delimiters, but the error shows back slash. Does this have anything to do with the error?

Comment: It still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and running this fixed it.

```
sudo gem install em-websocket
```